# Inclusion of trigonometry functions in simple calculator, C++

Tags: c++, calculator

I am currently working on a small and simple calculator program and it's coming along very well, but I'm just trying to make some improvements. It includes adding in functions for sin/cos/tan and abs.

I couldn't think of any other way which I could include them in as I have already declared my variables as float earlier on in the code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //Variables that user inputs.
    float a, b;
    char op;

    //Input them in the order
    std::cin >> a >> op >> b;

    //Addition
    if (op == '+') {
        std::cout << a << '+' << b << '=' << a+b;
    }
    //Subtraction
    else if (op == '-') {
    std::cout << a << '-' << b << '=' << a-b;
    }
    //Multiplication
    else if (op == '*') {
        std::cout << a << '*' << b << '=' << a*b;
    }
    //Division
    else if (op == '/') {
        std::cout << a << '/' << b << '=' << a/b;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Apologies. Realised I didn't include the question. How do I include the trigonometric functions?

Comment: What's the question? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: What's your exact problem ? What have you tried that did not work/wasn't what you wanted ?

Comment: So, as a start, you probably need to figure out how to read a string instead of a char for the `op`. The rest should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Check OP before redirecting to b.  Maybe you can accommodate two different input formats.

Comment: Apologies! Edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do this , but for your curiosity, can have something like following :

(make sure you do necessary checks)

```
     /* Sine */
    else if (op == 's') {
        std::cout << a<<"*sin(" << b << ")=" << a*sin(b);
    }

    /* Cosine */
    else if (op == 'c') {
        std::cout << a<<"*cos(" << b << ")=" << a*cos(b);
    }

   /* Tangent */
    else if (op == 't') {
        std::cout << a<<"*tan(" << b << ")=" << a*tan(b);
    }

   /* Absolute */
    else if (op == 'a') {
        std::cout << a<<"*abs(" << b << ")=" << a*fabs(b);
    }
```

Comment: Is there no way to include it as a word like 'cos' or 'sin'? I could have done this but thought it'd be much better to do it in words. :\

Comment: @xbili you need to read string as input and parse them accordingly

Comment: #include <string>

std::string op;
if( op == "a" )

elseif ( op == "cos" )
elseif ( op == "magic" )